# How to Achieve Thread.Sleep() Functionality in Unity Script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, thread-sleep

I am building a vuforia based Augmented Reality Application.I need to add sleep to some part of scripts but i am unable to achieve it.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your code/actual problem it is dificult to give an answer that reaches further than being very generic:

Whenever you want some kind of wait functionality in Unity you should use

#### [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

using e.g. [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html), [`WaitUntil`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html), [`WaitWhile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitWhile.html) among others.

```c#
private IEnumerator DoSomething()
{
    // doing something

    // waits 5 seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

    // do something else
}
```

you start this from another method (inside a MonoBehaviour script) using

```c#
StartCoroutine(DoSomething());
```

---

#### Invoke

While Coroutines are more used for little animations like smooth movements etc for a simple timer you can also use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)

```c#
Invoke(nameof(DoSomething), 5.0f);

...

// will be called after 5 seconds
private void DoSomething()
{
    // do something
}
```

---

#### Simple Update timer

Ofcourse it is also possible to simply wait within the `Update` method of MonoBehaviours e.g. something like

```c#
private float timer;
private bool activateSleep;

private void Update()
{
    if(activateSleep)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timer <= 0)
        {
            activateSleep = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // return so the rest of Update is not done
            return;
        }
    }

    // Otherwise do what you would usually do
}

public void ActivateSleep(float forSeconds)
{
    timer = forSeconds;
    activateSleep = true;
}
```

but you already see how "beautiful" that gets ...

Comment: The former method isn't working for me. Does this require the use of a special library or something?

Comment: @AidanofVT as you can see all the links are from the Unity API .. no special library. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: The script makes it's way to the WaitForSeconds call, but it doesn't cause the program to wait.